# How to implement "Auto Generate Animation" and "Visualize" buttons in custom Button inspector?

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ui, editors

I extended the Button class with my own variables. I also had to create an Editor script since Unity manually draws the Button's fields into the Inspector. I just need to know what the functions that are called by these two buttons in the Inspector:

[image]

I've googled the topic and nothing came up in my results.

I'm on Unity 2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to use the `Window > Analysis > IMGUI Debugger` to inspect the buttons. Fortunately, the call trace to which function is called.

[image]
[image: image 2]

Also, since there's a `SelectableEditor`, I don't have to re-serialize all the properties of the button. I just extend my custom editor class from `SelectableEditor` like so:

```cs
[CustomEditor(typeof(CustomScript))]
public class CustomEditor : SelectableEditor
{
    SerializedProperty customVar;

    protected override void OnEnable()
    {
        base.OnEnable();

        // add code here. for example:
        customVar = serializedObject.FindProperty("animateType");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        // add code here. for ex.
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(customVar);

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Comment: will accept my answer in two days